# how do I changed the password policy in LibreElec

Tags: busybox, passwd, kodi

I believe LibreElec is using some form of BusyBox. I've done lots searching and been unable to find where password rules can be changed. Since my LibreElec media player is not  connected to the internet, I feel fine using short numeric passwords. It's my machine and am willing to deal with any consequences that result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do it with the **passwd** command as it will enforce rules.
Use the **cryptpw** command it will generate an encrypted string you can then substitute back into the **/etc/shadow** file

Here I'm generating a crypt script for the password admin

```
LibreELEC:~ # echo 'admin' | cryptpw
$6$Rrh2e2Mj0JZtmZCR$kH36K7V0TB2inCzJSfZ/MEJVNF2I8yVigdm4P0MSxMt9ogd2Kp8TpuZiKac0sqzmmhAUZi6FZ0psc6q9jKvAW.
```

Then edit the Shadow password file and substitute what is currently there.

```
LibreELEC:/etc # vi /etc/shadow
systemd-timesync:*:::::::
systemd-network:*:::::::
dbus:*:::::::
root:$6$k9KsP.aTXJTCt8oh$Is6fU9hE9dmcjOITBc/qQ3do1v5UIuN1XfmOdRDnIiqgZjcHUS9szFwD8UT/WXKSBiFW8vwKsv9n8MkbZPFlO.:18461::::::
nobody:*:::::::
system:*:::::::
avahi:*:::::::
LibreELEC:~ #
```

Verify with a separate SSH session before you logout!

Comment: Great answer, just was I needed